# Configure Apache to use external proxy for internet connection

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

In my application I am using following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/ajax(.*) http://api.externalserver.com/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Now the problem is that my corporate network requires me to use HTTP proxy for external internet connections.

To ilustrate, this doesn't work:

```
curl -v http://api.externalserver.com/login
```

But this works:

```
curl -v -x 11.22.11.22:8585 http://api.externalserver.com/login
```

How can I make Apache use the corporate proxy for external internet requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you'll want to enable `mod_proxy_http`, and set:

```
ProxyRemote * http://11.22.11.22:8585
```

somewhere in your virtualhost configuration.

Comment: where do I have to set this?

Comment: where is mod_proxy_http?!

Comment: @nickgrim , where do we have to set this?? somewhere!!

Answer (score 2):

You may install SQUID proxy in transparent mode to proxy all traffic going from local machine to the internet.

For this first add iptables rule

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:3128
```

this will redirect all outgoing http connections to local squid.
Then configure squid according to this [guide](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/TransparentProxy.html#s4) and additionaly configure

```
cache_peer 11.22.11.22 parent 8585 0 no-query default
never_direct allow all
```

That's all. All your outgoing traffic to port 80 will go through your organisation proxy

Answer (score 1):

Did you try http tunneling, via proxytunnel or corkscrew ?

You need to configure a vhost for your Apache and use it as a distant proxy.

Maybe adapting this could help you : http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is mod_proxy, and mod_proxy_http specifically:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

Answer (score 0):

After setting `ProxyRemote` and restarted `httpd`, if you got the "[error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to failed", then you also need to execute the following:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```